# При return list.sorted выдает ошибка null

Tags: java, spring, java-8

у меня есть список POJO мне нужно вывести их, но этого их надо сортировать по полю LatestPrice. При сортировке программа выдает ошибку null. Связи чем это может происходит ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следует либо отфильтровать значения, содержащие `null`:

```java
public List<Statistics> getList() {
    return statisticsService.listAll()
        .stream()
        .filter(stat -> stat != null && stat.getLatestPrice() != null)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Statistics::getLatestPrice))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

либо отсортировать *по полю*, используя `Comparator.nullsLast`:

```java
public List<Statistics> getList() {
    return statisticsService.listAll()
        .stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .sorted(Comparator.nullsLast(
            Comparator.comparingDouble(Statistics::getLatestPrice)
        ))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Также для таких задач можно использовать Spring Data и [`PagingAndSortingRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html) или реализовать метод вида `findByOrderByLatestPrice` в обычном `JpaRepository<Statistics>`.

Comment: Спасибо большое ))